# IE 8 jwplayer in colorbox

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jwplayer

Error in IE browser(IE 10 in 8 mode) - Unable to get property 'SetReturnValue' error in IE 8

Error in IE tester null is null or is not an object in IE 8

Both give the error in line 1

The jwplayer is loaded from ajax request in colorbox.

**The player works for the first time but crashes when the colorbox is closed and gives the above error

```
<div id="welcome-video" class="colorBoxInline" style="height:500px;width: 700px;">
    <div id='jw-video'>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
jwplayer('jw-video').setup({
file: "<?php echo $base_url;?>new_media/tutorial/welcome.mp4",
image:"<?php echo $base_url;?>new_media/tutorial/welcome.jpg",
width: 700,
height: 500
})</script>
```

Comment: Do you have an example that we can look at?

Comment: cant share the link it is password protected i will try to replicate it and send the whole code

Comment: Can you email it then? - http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us